# How to assign the handler to the correct play button

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Clicking a play button starts all videos that have been previously played - the stop button works and no video is playing when the play buttons are on display.

Starting the videos other than the one play button that was previously clicked is supposed to start, and the other videos are supposed to be stopped.

That is the bug that needs to be fixed.

Clicking one of the play buttons when videos are stopped should only start one video, not multiple videos.

**To reproduce issue:** Click on one play button, and the video loads.

Then Click on the **X**

Now click on a different play button and you will see, the video that was clicked on before is now playing, along with the video I just clicked on. So now there are 2 videos playing at the same time.

---

This code is run each time I create a new player.

I am assigning the handler to play the video to every play button which is why all the videos play at once.

How do I assign the handler to the correct play button for that player?

How would I find the specific play button I need?

Click **Run**, not update to test code.

Code: https://jsitor.com/EBO8gdOs0c

Backup copy: https://jsfiddle.net/5etxr1kg/

```
function createPlayHandler(player) {
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".thePlay");
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.playVideo();
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: That is a song, not a YouTube video, both are different types of codes. I don't understand how to have that work in my code that uses a youtube video. https://jsitor.com/EBO8gdOs0c

Comment: Your code deals with audio, not a YouTube video. Both are different types of codes.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work in my code? https://jsitor.com/EBO8gdOs0c And it worked fine for you? Can you check to see if it works?

Comment: The two codes I think are set up too differently, that's why I asked if you were able to get it to work.

Comment: Very complex code. Unnecessarily so. I reopened. You will need to refactor that to even start adding what you need.  Why not have a simple embed? Why the iFrames?